# Custom font size in a math aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, relsize

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I need help in finding a way to increase the font size in a  math aligned environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize} 

\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}
    #1
    \end{align*}}


\begin{document}

\eq{
\fontsize{20}{20}
    &F=ky\\
    &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
}


\end{document}
```

I have tried using the `\large` and the `\fontsize{}{}` command and it has not worked. I would be greatful if someone could help me out in ajusting the font size of my equations. Ideally I would like a solution where I can enter another parameter into my `\eq` command to control the font size.

Comment: Try with `\begingroup\Huge\begin{align*}
 #1
 \end{align*}\endgroup`

Comment: @Ivan Thanks a bunch! Your solution works! Just out of curiosity, what exactly does the `\begingroup \endgroup` do to fix this, sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`  are required to limit the action of the `\Huge` command. Without that group, the text after the `\eq` command would also be in Huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is an unconventional solution which uses the `fontsize` package. We define the new environment `myalign*` with an optional argument which takes one of the font sizing commands provided by `fontsize`. This should be sufficient for most concrete cases.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=10pt]{fontsize} 

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myalign*}[1][]{%
 \csname#1\endcsname
 \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
 \endalign
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal size 

\begin{myalign*}
 &F=ky\\
 &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{myalign*}

\begin{myalign*}[normalsizer]
&F=ky\\
&W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{myalign*}

\begin{myalign*}[normalsizerr]
 &F=ky\\
 &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{myalign*}

\begin{myalign*}[normalsizerrr]
 &F=ky\\
 &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{myalign*}

\begin{myalign*}[Larger]
 &F=ky\\
 &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{myalign*}
 
 Normal size
 
\end{document}
```

If you want full control over the font and the line spacing you will need something similar:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xmyalign*}[2]{%
 \fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont
 \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
 \endalign
}
\makeatother
```

To use, for example, like this:

```
\begin{xmyalign*}{60}{60}
 &F=ky\\
 &W = \frac{1}{2}ky^2
\end{xmyalign*}
```